# IE 11 - Issue In Displaying Byte Array Image

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, arraybuffer

I have used the following code

```
 $scope.download = function() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    request.onload = function() {
     var blob = new Blob([request.response], {type: "image/png"})
      var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        $scope.apiImgSrc = urlCreator.createObjectURL( blob );
         angular.element("#apiImage").attr('src', $scope.apiImgSrc);
       }
    request.open("POST", "/customer/downloadlogo");
      request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
      request.send(JSON.stringify({
     "customerSeq": 1000,
      "userId": "TEST-USER"
 }));
```

}

It is not working in IE 11 and returns the error as the following image

Comment: You forgot to put the image.

Comment: thanks for your concern @mako

Comment: So... could we have this error message ?

Comment: [object DOMException]{ABORT_ERR: 20, code: 11, constructor: DOMException {...}, DATA_CLONE_ERR: 25, DOMSTRING_SIZE_ERR: 2, HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: 3, INDEX_SIZE_ERR: 1, INUSE_ATTRIBUTE_ERR: 10, INVALID_ACCESS_ERR: 15, INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: 5, INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR: 13, INVALID_NODE_TYPE_ERR: 24, INVALID_STATE_ERR: 11, message: "InvalidStat...", name: "InvalidStat...", NAMESPACE_ERR: 14, NETWORK_ERR: 19, NO_DATA_ALLOWED_ERR: 6, NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR: 7, NOT_FOUND_ERR: 8, NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: 9 ...} this is the error i receive

Comment: Hi @VinothNandhakumar, Is it only issue with IE 11?? What about other browsers??